# In MySQL 5, how do I write a "not exists" subquery in terms of joins?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, innodb

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37 (InnodB engine).  I have read that for performance reasons, it may be better to rewrite a subquery as something involving joins.  Below is an extremely simplified version of the query I want to run ...

```
select m.* from msg m where    
    not (exists (select mr.ID from msg_read mr where mr.MESSAGE_ID=m.ID and mr.RECIPIENT='USER1')) and m.AUTHOR<>'USER1';
```

I can't figure out how to rewrite "not exists" in terms of joins.  Can someone provide some guidance along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and then test whether the matching column from the table being joined is `NULL`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM msg AS m
LEFT JOIN msg_read AS mr
    ON mr.message_id = m.id AND mr.recipient = 'USER1'
WHERE m.author <> 'USER1'
AND mr.message_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the equivalent of your query using a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM msg m
LEFT JOIN msg_read mr
    ON m.ID = mr.MESSAGE_ID AND mr.RECIPIENT = 'USER1'
WHERE mr.ID IS NULL AND m.AUTHOR <> 'USER1'
```

However, to be sure of which version of your query performs better, you should run each through EXPLAIN and compare the execution plans. Check the [EXPLAIN manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) for details.
I've seen a lot of cases on MySQL where an EXISTS sub-query was actually faster than the equivalent join!

Comment: Barmar got it first : )